# S3 Vibration pattern

Tags: android, design-patterns, vibration

Samsung Galaxy S3 has function for customize vibrations through vibration patterns. We would like to change this patterns programmatically (enable/disable within our app), but we couldn't find any api. Is there any way to do this? Thank you for any reply

Comment: If I understand Your question the right way, You want to to some vibrations inside Your app? Or Do You want to change the patterns that are made by the user on Galaxy S3?

Comment: The second part is correct...thank You in advance